# Как настроить передачу файлов на облако с помощью IBM Aspera on Cloud через API?

Tags: python, ibm

Хочу передавать файлы с локальной машины (windows 10) в IBM Cloud Storage при помощи REST API и их технологии Aspera. Всё на Python. Не могу пока понять всю цепочку действий и какие необходимы ключи/токены для этого.
Например, у меня есть:

1. Хранилище IBM Storage с названием storage_name
2. Внутри хранилища bucket с названием bucket_name
3. COS_ENDPOINT = "https://s3.ap.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
4. COS_API_KEY_ID = "my_key"
5. COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
6. COS_SERVICE_CRN = "my_crn"
7. COS_STORAGE_CLASS = "ap-geo-lite"

Не могу в их официальной документации понять, какие ключи и в какой последовательности нужно получать. Как и каким из ключей авторизовываться при запросах к Aspera? Как правильно запускать их клиент для передачи данных?

P.S. Знаю, что есть библиотека для работы с Aspera. Но она только на 3.6, а у нас 3.7 на проекте.

P.S.S. Перед тем, как поставите свой минус моему вопросу: документацию читал, английский понимаю, не прошу сделать за меня - прошу объяснить шаги, если вы имели опыт работы с Aspera.

Спасибо:)